# Update statement not working in python?

Tags: python, oracle, jdbc

I've written a simple python program, which get Data form database successfully. but unable to update table in DB. 
When executing update statement it's get stuck and nothing happen, no any exception.

My code is as follows. Any idea whyis this ?

```
from java.sql import DriverManager

    def updateDB():

        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.1.1.1:1521:auid"
        uname = "dbtstj1"
        pword = "dbtstj321"

        conn = None
        stmt = None

        try:
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,uname,pword)
            stmt = conn.createStatement()

            rs = stmt.executeQuery("select PKG_NAME from PkgData")
            while rs.next():
                print rs.getString(1)

            pkgName = "'Test Pkg Name'"
            pkgID = "'T1234'"

            updateQuary = "UPDATE PkgData SET PKG_NAME =%s WHERE PKG_ID =%s" %(pkgName, pkgID)

            stmt.execute(updateQuary)

        except Exception , e:
            print 'Error:', e[0]

        finally:
            if stmt is not None:
                stmt.close()
            if conn is not None:
                conn.close()

    updateDB()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These type of issues can be happen when query request datatype and required datatype is difference.
It seems to be there was a mismatch with database's datatype and your query. Can you recheck with database's datatype with your query.
For Ex: PKG_ID =%s can be another data type in database as digit or etc...

Comment: yes that was the my mistake. that resolve problem. now it's working ... Thank you... :D

Answer (score 1):

you need to commit your changes to the database:

```
stmt.execute(updateQuary)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: we cannot go further in "stmt.execute(updateQuary)". It get stuck in this line and no any exception given.